# What does "Error: Layer not found: -1" from ArcGIS Silverlight API 2.4 mean?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

We are using ESRI SL 2.4 API- and our application has one dynamic service and one feature layer. Only few of the users getting below error, not sure whether this is issue with Microsoft sliverlight version. Any quick help on this.

Error: Layer not found: -1

at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Layer.OnInitializationFailed(EventArgs e)
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Layer.Initialize()
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.FeatureLayer.info_Error(Object sender, TaskFailedEventArgs e)
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.FeatureService.FeatureLayerInfo.OnError(Exception err)
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.FeatureService.FeatureLayerInfo.Execute_Completed(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)

Comment: Which web browser you are using ?

Comment: You can view a layer with ArcGIS Desktop ?

Comment: Its IE8 and yes I can see in ArcGIS Desktop.